# Нарисовать линию в CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно нарисовать такую линию в `CSS`, чтобы она масштабировалась и растягивалась по ширине экрана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.line-first {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 250%;
  color: $pinkcolor;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f50057;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 22.4%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.line-middle {
  position: relative;
  top: -52px;
  left: 389px;
  border: 2px solid #f50057;
  width: 85px;
  height: 0px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.line-second {
  border-top: 4px solid #f50057;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="splitters">
  <div class="line-second"></div>
  <p class="line-first">Title</p>
  <div class="line-middle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css/726071#726071

Answer (score 15):

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  order: 1;
}

h1:before {
  width: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red calc(50% - 1px), red calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
}

h1:after {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Заголовок</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 11):

При чём тут `react` понять сложно. На `css` можно сделать так:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:15px;
}
.line-block{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  color:red;
}
.line-block__title{
  flex:0 0 auto;
  padding:5px 40px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:400;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.line-block__title:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.line-block__title:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  transform-origin:left bottom;
  border-right:1px solid;
  transform:skewX(-39deg);
}
.line-block:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-top:1px solid;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-block">
  <h3 class="line-block__title" contenteditable>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

UPD. В первом варианте левый край линии оказался скошен. Исправил.

По старинке, без флексбоксов и закрывая один псевдоэлемент фоном от другого. Зато подстраивается и под длину текста, и под количество строк в нём.

Отступы и высоту строки можно ставить любые. От угла наклона зависит только прибавка к толщине боковой границы. Этой прибавкой компенсируем сужение границы при трансформации сдвига.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/wQdPQG

```css
.broken-line {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.broken-line > span {
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 15px;  /* для красоты, можно убрать или поменять */
  position: relative;
}

.broken-line:before,
.broken-line > span:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skew(-60deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.broken-line:before {
  border-top: 4px solid red;
}

.broken-line > span:before {
  background: white;  /* заслонить часть псевдоэлемента у родителя */
  border-right: 8px solid red;  /* толще, чтобы компенсировать трансформацию */
  bottom: -4px;  /* вниз на толщину границы родителя */
}
```

```html
<h2 class="broken-line"><span>Текст</span></h2>

<h2 class="broken-line"><span>Длинный текст <br>в две строки</span></h2>
```

---

Первый вариант, со скошенным левым краем у линии. Может быть, тоже пригодится.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/JeNomd

```css
.broken-line {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.broken-line > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 15px;  /* для красоты, можно убрать или поменять */
  position: relative;
}

.broken-line:before,
.broken-line > span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: skew(-60deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.broken-line:before {
  border-top: 4px solid red;
}

.broken-line > span:before {
  background: white;  /* заслонить часть псевдоэлемента у родителя */
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  border-right: 8px solid red;  /* толще, чтобы компенсировать трансформацию */
}
```

```html
<h2 class="broken-line"><span>Текст</span></h2>

<h2 class="broken-line"><span>Длинный текст <br>в две строки</span></h2>
```

Comment: Что значить `>` в css?

Comment: @nicolaa Это [дочерний селектор](https://webref.ru/css/selector/child). Стиль будет применён только к тому `span`, который является непосредственным потомком `.broken-line`.

Answer (score 6):

```css
.firstline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}

.middleline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 29px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.secondline {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 55%;
  position: relative;
  left: -7px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.conatiner {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstline">Title</div>
  <div class="middleline"></div>
  <div class="secondline">.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще вариант с `svg`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #f50057;
  padding: 0 0 0 20%;
  margin: 20px 0 -25px 0;
  
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-head">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 20" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd">
      <path 
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
            stroke="#f50057" 
            stroke-width="2"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            fill="none"
            d="M 0,20 L 80,20 100,0 200,0"/>
      
    </svg>
</div>
```